# Powershell Copy-Item exclude folder

Tags: powershell-4.0

I want to copy folder with some folder exclusion

```
Copy-Item C:\temp\src -Destination C:\temp\backup\src -Force -Recurse -Exclude 'C:\temp\src\excludeFolder'
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you give us some more information?  For example, what does the command above do when you run it?

Comment: I want to copy all files (including sub-directories)  recursively from "C:\temp\src" to "C:\temp\backup\src" except one folder "C:\temp\src\excludeFolder"

But the above command copy all the files. -Exclude doesn't work

Comment: Strange, this works fine for me.  It copies the exclude folder but not the contents (the files) from that.

Comment: I am using PowerShell version 5.1.16299.98

Comment: 5.1.14393 for me, seems unlikely to be that.  I did have speech marks around my source and destination but I can't see it being that.